# How closely should the homepage design match the app design?

Tags: homepage, landing-page, branding

We have a team consisting of CEO, Product Manager/UX guy, UI Designer and Front-end developer who all discuss design, UX and usability questions for [our app at www.enthuse.me](http://www.enthuse.me)

We all agree that the homepage can be different to the app as long as the 'feeling' of the brand is still there.

Two (2) of us think that the below designs are close enough that there should be no confusion that the app and homepage are part of the same brand/product.

Two (2) of us think that the designs are too different (specifically because of textured backgrounds, more skeuomorphic elements on homepage than on flat design app, and more use of colour on the homepage) and that this might cause confusion.

[image: Home page of site]

[image: About page of site]

[image: User page on site]

What do you think? Is there enough of a difference between the two to 'matter' - does a difference in this case matter at all? How could the designs be brought more into line to work 'better' together?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, just to restate,

> The homepage can be different as long as the 'feeling' of the brand is still the same.

Couldn't agree more. In my opinion, the current homepage doesn't provide the same feeling.

On the topic of design, your app might be flat, but you can still have skeuomorphic elements.

- Take *spendee* for example (http://www.spendeeapp.com)
- or *kelvin app* (http://www.kelvinapp.com)

Both of these have non-flat designs for their homepage, but it still conveys the feeling of the brand.

Then there is a completely different style of homepage which matches the design of the flat app itself.

- *Taasky* (http://www.taasky.com)
- *Geckoboard* (http://www.geckoboard.com)

Hence, it doesn't matter if you go for a flat design or a skeuomorphic or just non-flat one, the feeling can be be the same in both these cases.

In your case, I would suggest that you lose the background gradient to start with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the helpful links. By gradient, do you mean the grey textured background, or the blurred photographic bg at the top?

Comment: The grey textured background.

Answer (score 0):

The application and the product website can be completely different.

The connection between both on [Matlab website](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) is kept only by screenshots and the product logo.

In [another case](http://www.digsilent.de/index.php/products-powerfactory.html) there is however something missing, that we could call the spirit or (citing you) "feeling of the brand".

I don't see such connections in your case. The textures, colors and fonts should be the same, but you may experiment with different positioning of elements. The connection would be kept, without losing the spirit (or "feeling"), but it would be obvious that these two website are different.